# Kaltura -- Internal Server Error Occured

Tags: video, upload, media

I'm having error while `Uploading any Content` (or) accessing the `[ Content ] Tab`, inside the Kaltura Management Console. I'm with Administrator role.

It is showing like:

[image]

In the `kaltura_api_v3.log` file:

```
2012-07-10 19:35:52 [127.0.0.1] [2090136132] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] NOTICE: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/general/myCache.class.php line 39 - Memcache::connect(): Server example.mydomain.com (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Connection refused (111)
2012-07-10 19:35:52 [127.0.0.1] [2090136132] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/general/myCache.class.php line 39 - Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to example.mydomain.com:11211, Connection refused (111)
2012-07-10 19:35:52 [127.0.0.1] [2090136132] [API] [myCache->myCache] NOTICE: ERROR: Error while trying to connect to memcache. Make sure it is properly running on example.mydomain.com:11211
2012-07-10 19:35:52 [127.0.0.1] [2090136132] [API] [kPermissionManager::addPartnerGroupAction] NOTICE: Permission item id [571] is not of type PermissionItemType::API_ACTION_ITEM but still defined in partner group permission id [117]
2012-07-10 19:35:52 [127.0.0.1] [2090136132] [API] [kPermissionManager::addPartnerGroupAction] NOTICE: Permission item id [633] is not of type PermissionItemType::API_ACTION_ITEM but still defined in partner group permission id [117]
2012-07-10 19:35:52 [127.0.0.1] [48976061] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] NOTICE: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/general/myCache.class.php line 39 - Memcache::connect(): Server example.mydomain.com (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Connection refused (111)
2012-07-10 19:35:52 [127.0.0.1] [48976061] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/general/myCache.class.php line 39 - Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to example.mydomain.com:11211, Connection refused (111)
2012-07-10 19:35:52 [127.0.0.1] [48976061] [API] [myCache->myCache] NOTICE: ERROR: Error while trying to connect to memcache. Make sure it is properly running on example.mydomain.com:11211
2012-07-10 19:35:53 [127.0.0.1] [48976061] [API] [kPermissionManager::addPartnerGroupAction] NOTICE: Permission item id [571] is not of type PermissionItemType::API_ACTION_ITEM but still defined in partner group permission id [117]
2012-07-10 19:35:53 [127.0.0.1] [48976061] [API] [kPermissionManager::addPartnerGroupAction] NOTICE: Permission item id [633] is not of type PermissionItemType::API_ACTION_ITEM but still defined in partner group permission id [117]
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] NOTICE: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/general/myCache.class.php line 39 - Memcache::connect(): Server example.mydomain.com (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Connection refused (111)
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/general/myCache.class.php line 39 - Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to example.mydomain.com:11211, Connection refused (111)
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [myCache->myCache] NOTICE: ERROR: Error while trying to connect to memcache. Make sure it is properly running on example.mydomain.com:11211
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:02 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->errorHandler] WARN: /opt/kaltura/app/infra/KAutoloader.php line 52 - require_once(): Unable to allocate memory for pool.
2012-07-10 19:36:03 [81.152.216.67] [1659128380] [API] [KalturaFrontController->getExceptionObject] CRIT: exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to connect to any Sphinx config' in /opt/kaltura/app/infra/db/DbManager.php:157
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/kaltura/app/plugins/sphinx_search/lib/SphinxCriteria.php(169): DbManager::getSphinxConnection()
#1 /opt/kaltura/app/plugins/sphinx_search/lib/SphinxCriteria.php(359): SphinxCriteria->executeSphinx('kaltura_entry', 'WHERE display_i...', 'ORDER BY create...', 50, 1000, true, '')
#2 /opt/kaltura/app/alpha/lib/model/entryPeer.php(449): SphinxCriteria->applyFilters()
#3 /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3/lib/KalturaEntryService.php(883): entryPeer::doSelect(Object(SphinxEntryCriteria))
#4 /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3/services/BaseEntryService.php(441): KalturaEntryService->listEntriesByFilter(Object(KalturaMediaEntryFilter), Object(KalturaFilterPager))
#5 [internal function]: BaseEntryService->listAction(Object(KalturaMediaEntryFilter), Object(KalturaFilterPager))
#6 /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3/lib/KalturaServiceReflector.php(293): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3/lib/KalturaDispatcher.php(85): KalturaServiceReflector->invoke('list', Array)
#8 /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3/lib/KalturaFrontController.php(246): KalturaDispatcher->dispatch('baseentry', 'list', Array)
#9 /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3/lib/KalturaFrontController.php(90): KalturaFrontController->handleMultiRequest()
#10 /opt/kaltura/app/api_v3/web/index.php(19): KalturaFrontController->run()
#11 {main}
```

Then what should i do? :(

Answer (score 1):

The exception shows that the system cannot connect to sphinx.
Check that 'searchd' process is running and run it if not (there should be a script under /opt/kaltura/app/scripts)

Memcache should be optional, but it is definitely recommended for performance.
You can install it from the repository of your Linux distro.

Comment: When i command `# searchd` it is showing: `bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...` many lines. What should i do? :(

Comment: You need to start searchd service, like: # /etc/init.d/searchd restart

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues. Your PHP doesn't have enough memory or your box seems run out of memory.

For php you could increase *memory_limit* value in */etc/php.ini* (requires web server restart)

Another thing is that memcached server seems unavailable. if it runs on different box you may want to check firewall settings.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all files in /opt/kaltura/log/sphinx/data/ and start sphinx again.